# componentDidMount() how to do a setState()

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to migrate to React 17 and I want to change

```js
componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({ model: this.props.formModel })
}
```

to React 17

```js
componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({ model: this.props.formModel })
}
```

But I have this error in `componentDidMount`

> Do not use setState in componentDidMount

Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you want to migrate from React 15.x to 16.x? 17 is not yet released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon this warning is from ESLint. It's a rule that was implemented back in the days when calling `setState` in componentDidMount caused visible render flash. This is no longer the case so you can just disable the rule.

However, if you're setting an initial state, this should happen in your constrcutor. See here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

Answer (score 1):

Already we must understand that it has a difference between the two : componentWillMount and componentDidMount

```
componentWillMount is called before the render and
componentDidMount is much more used to update the dom

componentDidMount is the perfect place to make your setState()
you will rarely need to use componentWillMount for this kind of action.
```

maybe you could show more your code so that we can see why you have this error :

> Do not use setState in componentDidMount

it's may be because of your linter as christian say

Answer (score 1):

About why you shouldn't call setState inside componentDidMount, you can take a look at [React document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

You can set the state from props in your constructor like this:

```
class ReactComp(Component):
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            model: props.formModel
        }
    }
```

But this will work for the first time React mount this component for you. When the data changed, the state won't reflect. So I refer to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead, this is also a recommend way to implement due to componentWillMount will be deprecated in a couple of releases.

```
class ReactComp(Component):
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (props.formModel !== state.formModel) {
            return {
                formModel: props.formModel,
            };
        }

        // Return null to indicate no change to state.
        return null;
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `componentDidMount()`. You can use `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.state.model !== prevProps.formModel) {

     this.state({ model : prevProps.formModel})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to use

```js
state = ({ model: this.props.formModel })
```

don't need to call `componentDidMount`

Comment: don't set state directly in a react component unless you're initialising it. ie. `this.state = ....` is fine in the constructor.

Comment: this statement is wrong. initializing the state for `this.state = {model : ''}` instead of using parenthesis `()`

Comment: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e Put props to set an initial state is an anti pattern